# "ValueError: Couldn't find 'checkpoint' file or checkpoints in given directory" error with Google's object detection tutorial

Tags: tensorflow, google-console-developer

I'm following Google's object detection tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/algorithms/object-detection#submit-job), but when I run the job, I get the following error:

`ValueError: Couldn't find 'checkpoint' file or checkpoints in given directory gs://cloud-samples-data/ai-platform/built-in/image/pretrained_checkpoints/detection/`

Is this error something specific to my setup, or is there something broken? How can I provide more information?

Comment: Same issue for me. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same error. Inspecting the [provided gs location](https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/cloud-samples-data/ai-platform/built-in/image/pretrained_checkpoints/), the `pretrained_checkpoints/` folder directory contains pre-trained checkpoints for both detection and classification.

In the detection/ directory, there is again a choice for different resnet backbones. As I chose the resnet50 in my algorithm config, I also chose the corresponding directory, making the entire `--pretrained_checkpoint_path` to fill in

`gs://cloud-samples-data/ai-platform/built-in/image/pretrained_checkpoints/detection/resnet50/`

instead of <s>`gs://cloud-samples-data/ai-platform/built-in/image/pretrained_checkpoints`</s>, as shown in the tutorial that you linked to.